# Solving optimization problems using derivatives and critical points

Tags: calculus, optimization, derivatives, convex-optimization

I have a homework question which I have completed 2/3 of; however I am stuck on the last part of the question.

The question is:

> A drug used to treat cancer is effective at low doses with an efficacy that increases with the quantity of the drug. However, at sufficiently high doses, the drug becomes lethal. For positive values of the constants k_1 and k_2, the fraction of patients surviving cancer with this drug treatment is given by
>   $$S(q)=\frac{q^2}{k_1^2+q^2}-\frac{q^2}{k_2^2+q^2}.$$

There are three parts to the question. I have answered the first two parts, but I don't know how to approach the last part, which in this case is question 3.

> 1) Find $S(0)$ and $\lim_{q\to\infty}S(q)$ and in each case explain what your findings mean in medical terms.

For part 1 I made $s(q)$ equal to $0$, which gave me
$$\frac 0 {k_1^2} - \frac 0 {k_2^2} = 0-0 = 0.$$
This indicates that when $q$ is equal to $0$, no patients have survived. I also used the limits for when $q$ is equal to $+\infty$; this gave me $(1-1)$, which is also equal to $0$. Therefore the conclusion here is that when $q$ is very high, hence infinity, the patients will not survive either.

> 2) What is the optimal daily drug quantity to administer in terms of $k_1$ and $k_2$?

For part two, I found the derivative of $s(q)$ and made is equal to $0$. So I found $s'(q)=0$.
This was a very long process which will take me forever to type here, however my final answer here was $q=\sqrt{k_2k_1}$, where $k_2$ and $k_1$ are constants. I am not sure if this is correct, but it looks pretty right to me.

> 3) Suppose Health Canada has only approved the use of the drug of up to 45 mg/day and suppose $k_1=25 \mathrm{mg}/\mathrm{day}$ is the same for all patients but $k_2$ varies from patient to patient. To determine a personalized treatment strategy it would be useful for physicians to have a plot of the optimal daily drug quantity as a function of $k_2$, call it $q∗(k_2)$. Sketch a plot of $q∗(k_2)$ and explain why you drew it that way. Hint: don't forget that $k_1<k_2$!

Tthis is the question that I need help approaching, any one care to help please? Am I meant to find the critical points..? Isn't that what I found in Part two? The graph it? If $k_2$ is meant to be greater than $k_1$ and $k_1$ is 25mg and overall it is 45mg, should $k_2$ be between 0 and 20mg?

Is this how my graph should be? [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your calculation of the optimal $q$ is correct.

The rest is easy. As a function of $k_2$, we have $q(k_2)=\sqrt{k_1k_2}=5\sqrt{k_2}$, at least for $25\lt k_2\lt 45$. This is not difficult to plot: the curve $y=5\sqrt{x}$ has a familiar shape. Our curve is (part of) a rightward opening parabola.

Comment: I found K2 to equal to 81, because K1<K2 and if K1 is equal to 25 then substituting the values into the local max I got in part 2, will give an answer of 81.

Comment: So I just plot y= 5 root x? What about the 81, do I start from 25? because k2 must be greater than k1? and it's max is 81?

Comment: You plot the curve $y=\sqrt{25x}=5\sqrt{x}$ for all permissible $x$, which means for all $x$ such that $25\lt x\le 45$. What $81$? There is no $81$ in the game. And by the way, it is not $q\ast k_2$, as in "times." It is $q(k_2)$, as in $q$ of $k_2$.

Comment: Ohh, the 81 I found is the domain so [25,81] How do I graph that? would k2 be my x axis?

Comment: The domain is $25$ to $45$, since max allowed dose is $45$. One could go beyond $45$ in case regulations change. The natural choice is to label the horizontal axis as $k_2$, and then the vertical axis can be labelled optimal dosage, or something like that.

Comment: I added an edit to my first post with at image of the graph, Is that how it should look? with my x axis as k2 and y axis as optimal dosage and thus highest would be sqrtK1K2

Comment: One more question.. How do I prove that the critical point so the local max found in part 2, is the local max? Other than the 2nd derivative test..

Comment: Taking second derivatives is usually not a good idea, too messy. More generally useful is the sign of the first derivative. But in this case I would argue thus. Take $k_2\gt k_1$, else we would not care about the drug. The survival function is $0$ when $q=0$, and positive near $0$ when $q$ is large. So the survival function attains a maximum somewhere. At the maximum, the derivative is $0$. But there is only **one place** in $(0,\infty)$ where the derivative is $0$ (you computed it). So what we found is it.

Comment: Thank you for your help!!! Is the graph that I plotted correct? I edited the image in to the very first post

Comment: You are welcome. Changes need to be made. You really should only draw the part from $k_2$ ("$x$") $=25$ to $x=45$. That part is not shown at all in your graph.

Comment: Ohh :s, I edited the first comment again, Is this one correct?

Comment: It looks right. There may be reason to get rid of the "dead space" below $y=20$ and above $y=40$, but that's a matter of presentation.

Comment: Alright perfect, I will Just draw it by hand! Thank you once again.